# How to format the string that have \r\n with <p> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby, the following string:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor\r\n          Sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\r\n       Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco\r\n    laboris nisi."
```

to the following:

```
"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p><p>Sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p><p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p> laboris nisi."
```

Comment: Replace all the \r\n with <br> using a regex?

Comment: I want it to be wrapped by `<p>...</p>` tags.

Comment: Split on \r\n, collect each wrapped with <p> tags, join with empty string.

Comment: Oh, @Qerub said that. Derek's is more like mine though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, there is a dedicated helper for this: simple_format.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Comment: The stated desired outcome lacks a trailing p tag, which simple_format would append. You could strip it after the fact or you could use gsub as I have above...

Answer (score 3):

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor\r\n          Sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\r\n       Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco\r\n    laboris nisi."

string.split("\r\n").map { |x| "<p>#{x.strip}</p>" }.join
```

evaluates to

```
"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p><p>Sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod\ntempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p><p>Ut enim ad minim \nveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p><p>laboris nisi.</p>"
```

which might be close enough (the last two words end up in a `<p>`). What do you say?

Comment: There is a Rails builtin way to handle this

Answer (score 2):

Odd that you'd not want the trailing `</p>`, but...

```
"<p>#{str.gsub(/\r\n\s*/, '</p><p>')}"
```

The gsub replaces the occurence of \r\n and any subsequent spaces with the close/open p tags.

Comment: @all: this works but Rails has a builtin way to handle this common need

Comment: @apneadiving: not exactly, assuming the original poster was accurate with his desired outcome.